# How to decrypt openssl encryped file with flag -nosalt -base64 and -md sha256?

Tags: encryption, openssl

Given this command:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -base64 -pass pass:aaaca -in flag.txt -out flag.txt.enc -md sha256
```

What's the format to decrypt openssl file? My openssl ubuntu version is 1.0.2g.

I'm asking because I tried using `openssl enc -d -aes-128-ecb -pass pass:aaaca -in flag.txt.enc -out pass.txt` but it says bad magic number with aaaca as password, and when I tried `openssl enc -d -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -base64 -md sha256 -in flag.txt.enc -out pass.txt -pass pass:aaaaa`  (with different password), it says bad decrypt. At this point, I'm not sure anymore. Thanks!

Edit: If you're wondering why am I purposely inputting the wrong password, it's because I'm trying to test out on brute forcing password for one of my assignment. Help appreciated ><

Answer (score 0):

> and when I tried `openssl enc -d -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -base64 -md sha256 -in flag.txt.enc -out pass.txt -pass pass:aaaaa` (with different password), it says bad decrypt.

Yes, of course, because the `openssl` command line  will perform [PKCS#7 compatible padding and unpadding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) by default. So if you decrypt with a wrong key then there is about a 255/256 chance of getting "bad decrypt" because the unpadding fails. If you're "lucky" the incorrect plaintext will contain a valid padding and you'll just get a wrong / randomized plaintext in the output.

So if you get into that situation then you'll have to check if the plaintext message does fit what you expect. If you have nothing to compare the possibly bad plaintext against, well, then you're in trouble as you may find multiple solutions to your problem.